# Jquery ajax: pass the scope to set it

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this class with this ajax call:

> Person = function () {
>
> ```
>     this.__type = "PersonDto:#Empower.Service.Common.Dto";
>     this.Name = undefined;
>     this.Surname = undefined;
>
>     this.GetById = function (id) {
>         return $.ajax({
>             type: "POST",
>             url: "/Services/PersonService.svc/GetPersonById",
>             data: JSON.stringify(id),
>             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>             dataType: "json",
>             success: function (data) {
>                 ...
>                 this = data;
>                 ...
>             }
>         });
>     }
> };
> ```

In success of ajax call i want to set the current instance of person, but "this" is not scope correct for setting.
There is a more elegant way than using a global variable?

Thank you in advance for your help, and I apologize for my bad English

Comment: notwithstanding your scope problem, you can't overwrite `this`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`jQuery.ajax()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method gives you a `context` property where you can set the value of `this` in the callbacks.

Just do:

```
context: this,
```

...in your call, as in:

```
this.GetById = function (id) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        context: this,  // <---- context property to set "this" in the callbacks
        url: "/Services/PersonService.svc/GetPersonById",
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

             // in here, "this" will be the same as in your "getById" method

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a global.

Just put:

```
 var self = this;
```

immediately before the `return $.ajax(...)` line, and then use `self` to reference the current instance inside the AJAX callback function.

This variable will only be in scope within the `GetById()` funciton.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can put `this` to a variable and then use that variable in your callback

```
var self = this;

this.GetById = function (id) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Services/PersonService.svc/GetPersonById",
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            ...
            self = data;
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, not `self = data`, probably, as that will just overwrite the previous value of "self".  More like, `self.something = data` or `self.something(data);` right?

Comment: @Pointy indeed, overwriting `self` will end up with a plain object without any methods attached to it, and wouldn't change `this` anyway.

Comment: Indeed you guys are right. In that case I assumed that data would be same as this without methods. Proper solution would be like Pointy said. Then we would need to know what callback function parameter data to give working solution to the problem

Comment: Using a closure septum "that", not the current instance of person. 

I followed the help of Patrick and I have reached my goal. Moreover, with Jquery.extend also prevents you from overwriting functions in my class